# How to activate collision to the shadow_hand

Tags: ros, gazebo, collision, shadow-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm working with a glove and the shadow hand of the shadow robot, the glove is working really good, but now i need to detect collisions with the shadow hand and other objects inside of gazebo.

Someone knows how to realize that?.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48931/how-to-activate-collision-to-the-shadow_hand/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

We have several gazebo touch sensors on the simulated hand. They are accessible on the topics name /..._bumper:

- /ffdistal_bumper
- /ffknuckle_bumper
- /ffmiddle_bumper
- ...

However they appear to be broken for the time being in Fuerte (see this [thread](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/13/contactsensor-in-gazebo-fuerte)). They should work in Gazebo 1.6.17 release but I don't know when that will happen...

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2012-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-23**:
hey, i read the thread but i dont know how can i patch, could you help me with this?

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2012-11-23**:
Sorry I didn't patch my version of Gazebo and I'm waiting for the next release hoping to have this annoying bug fixed so I can't help you with that I'm afraid.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-26**:
It's me again, i read that is a new release of the gazebo, do  you know how can i update the simutalor_gazebo to fix the problem with the contacsensors??

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2012-11-26**:
no, sorry I don't.